# Как определить url загружаемой страницы на сайте на Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Есть админка для сайта, у которой есть инструменты для управления, которые присутствуют на каждой странице (так как присутствую в layouts ). После того, как на сайт добавили несколько страниц для обычных гостей, инструменты управления там тоже видны.

Как определить url загружаемой страницы, чтобы контроллер мог решить, надо ли показывать элементы управления?

application.html.erb

```
<body>
    <% if ApplicationController.new.admin_view %>
        <!-- Skin configuration box -->
        <%= render 'layouts/skinconfig' %>
        <!-- Wrapper-->
        <div id="wrapper" class="<%= params[:controller] %>.<%= params[:action] %>">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
            <!-- Page wraper -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg <%= @extra_class %>">
                <!-- Page wrapper -->
                <%= render 'layouts/topnavbar' %>
                <!-- Main view  -->
                <%= yield %>
                <!-- Footer -->
                <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
            </div>
            <!-- End page wrapper-->
            <!-- Right sidebar -->
            <%= render 'layouts/rightsidebar' %>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <%= yield %>
    <% end %>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
    <!-- Include javascript per-controller - vendor plugins -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js") %>
    <!-- Include javascript per-view -->
    <!-- For demo purpose we include javascript in view but you can easily start SeedProject and organize it with Rails asset pipeline as you want -->
    <%= yield :javascript %>
</body>
```

application_controller.rb

```
# before_action :end_way_to_this_page, only: [:admin_view]
def admin_view
# список страниц для гостя:
# get "articles/:id/beauty", to: 'articles#beauty'
# get  "events/:id/beauty",  to:   'events#beauty'
# get 'WhitePark',  to:'pages#main'
# get 'otzivi',     to:'pages#review'
# get 'kuhnya',     to:'pages#kitchen'
# get 'statii',     to:'pages#article'
# get 'o_nas',      to:'pages#about_us'
# get 'map',        to:'pages#map_park'
# get 'sobitia',    to:'pages#eventlist'
# псевдокод:
# guestlist = [ 'otzivi', 'kuhnya', 'statii', 'o_nas', 'map', 'sobitia' ,beauty ]
# if guest_list.include?(@end_way) #если страница принадлежит этому списку
#   @admin_viev_mode = false # админпанель не видна
# else
#   @admin_viev_mode = true
# end
return true
end

# возращает строку, которая содержит символы после последнего / в адресе
# def end_way_to_this_page
#   full_way = way_to_this_page.to_s # <<<<<<<<< как реализовать? <<<<<<<<<
#   @end_way  = ""
#   full_way.each do |one_char|
#       if one_char == "/"
#           @end_way = ""
#       else
#           @end_way += one_char
#       end
#   end
# end
```

Comment: Странное решение. Почему бы не проверить вместо этого, является ли залогиненный администратором?

Comment: @D-side , потому-что для _любого_ пользователя _красивое оформление_ статьи должно выглядеть одинаково, а _информативное_ - всегда с админ панелью, но получать его должен только админ (вот тут можно настроить проверки доступа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю Вам нужен метод `current_page?(ваш_роут)`. Он проверяет соответствие с роутом. Вернет true если передан текущий роут и false в другом случае.
Аналогично себя ведет `if (action_name == 'мой рут')`

Comment: **NoMethodError** undefined method `current_page?' в строке @admin_viev_mode = !( current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'beauty') || current_page?(controller: 'events', action: 'beauty') )

Comment: Да, это хелпер, его нельзя использовать в контроллере

Comment: Можно, с помощью view_context.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере Вы можете использовать `params`.

Запрашиваемый контроллер: `params[:controller]`

Запрашиваемый action: `params[:action]`